# Unable to match desired schema for api

Tags: python, api, dictionary, dns

Im unable to formulate accurately enough this PUT request to the GoDaddy v1 domains api to update my A record. The only data point that needs to be updated is the ip address...... Im using python.

My code and error are reproduced below.

Also. Another question I have is whether I should be passing all the form values for the A record again or just the ones I desire to update. The GoDaddy api documentation indicates that this api is used to update ALL the dns records for the for the specified domain, type and name.

```py
domain1='ABC.COM'

key='ABCABC'

secret='ABCABC'

name='@'

args1 = {   
    'data':'ZXC.ZXC.ZXC.ZXC',
    'name':'@',
    'ttl': 600,
    'type':'A'
 }

heads1={
    'accept':'application/json',
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Authorization':'sso-key {}:{}'.format(key,secret)
}

url4='https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/{}/records/A/{}'.format(domain1,name)

response4=requests.put(url4,data=args1,headers=heads1)
```

Error:

```py
{'code': 'INVALID_BODY', 'fields': [{'code': 'INVALID_BODY', 'message': "invalid character 'd' looking for beginning of value", 'path': 'records'}], 'message': "Request body doesn't fulfill schema, see details in `fields`"}
```

**My initial hypothesis** about this error was that GoDaddy expects me to pass the payload as a nested dictionary where the first level of the dictionary is empty, and the data is present in the second level. If this is an accurate hypothesis, Im unable to formulate the args1 variable well enough to match the desired schema.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was within the Mulesoft API Designer, under Data Types, setting required to False.

How to set Data Types to not required

[image: How to set Data Types to not required]

Comment: Hey hey hey!!!!!!!!! So I don't remember now how I solved this... Something about nested dictionaries I think........... But I do know it worked out because Im not still struggling with this. :-) Thank you for your response, kind stranger, good luck with your work!

Comment: Glad to hear all sorted!
Happy I could help, you too :)